# $V$ be a vector space and $S\subseteq V$ be a set of linearly independent vectors.Then there is a basis $\beta$ so that $S\subseteq \beta \subseteq V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a vector space and let $S \subseteq V$ be a set of linearly independent vectors. Then, there exists a basis $\beta$ such that $S\subseteq \beta \subseteq V$.

> (a) Prove by induction (well-ordering)

> (b) Prove by Zorn's Lemma

I could prove it with Zorn's lemma easily but I'm not sure how to even start with the "Proof by induction".

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What's the dimension for $V$? Also in ZF the Zorn's lemma is equivalent to the well-ordering th.

Comment: Dimension is not mentioned so we had to assume that this statement is true for any dimension, finite or infinite.

Comment: @user1027216 yes I know about their equivalence but see I have to prove it using the standard form of principle of induction.

Answer (score 0):

You should use *transfinite induction*:

Let $B_0=S$. For a successor ordinal number $\alpha+1$, if $B_\alpha$ is not a basis yet, then there exist a vector $b_{\alpha+1}$ which is independent from $B_\alpha$. 
Then let $B_{\alpha+1}=B_\alpha\cup\{b_{\alpha+1}\}$.

For a limit ordinal $\alpha$, simply set $B_\alpha=\bigcup_{\tau<\alpha}B_\tau$.

This must end before $\alpha$ exceeds the cardinality of $V$.